# Perl Regular Expression default for non-matched

Tags: regex, perl

Lets say I do this:

```
my ($a,$b,$let) = $version =~ m/^(\d+)\.(\d+)\.?([A-Za-z])?$/;
```

so this will match for instance: 1.3a, 1.3,...
I want to have a default value for $let if let is not available, lets say, default 0.
so for 1.3 I will get:
$a = 1
$b = 3
$let = 0

is it possible? (from the regex it self, without using additional statements)

Thanks,

Comment: Not really. If you change it to `([A-Za-z]?)` you'll get `''` as a default value, but that's about it.

Comment: May I ask why you need to do this inline?

Comment: `$let = 0 unless defined $let`?

Comment: I dont, I actually used to do it exactly as most people suggest here, was just wondering if there was a better way which I'm not aware of, and seems like there isn't. (-:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work - updated to use bitwise or instead of ternary operator.

```
my ($a,$b,$let) = ($version =~ m/^(\d+)\.(\d+)\.?([A-Za-z])?$/) 
            && ($1,$2,$3 || 0 );
```

Here is a test script

```
&t("1.3");
&t("1.3a");
&t("1.3.a");

sub t {
$version = shift;
my ($a,$b,$let) = ($version =~ m/^(\d+)\.(\d+)\.?([A-Za-z])?$/) 
                && ($1,$2,$3 || 0 );
print "\n result $a.$b.$let";
}
```

Output is

```
result 1.3.0
result 1.3.a
result 1.3.a
```

original solution using ternary operator also works

```
my ($a,$b,$let) = ($version =~ m/^(\d+)\.(\d+)\.?([A-Za-z])?$/) 
            && (defined $3 ? ($1,$2,$3) : ($1,$2,0));
```

Answer (score 0):

`$let` should have a default value of `undef`.  You can test on that if you need to.